# How do Prometheus clients identify metric types?

Tags: prometheus

As per official documentation Prometheus doesn't keep the data type.

> These are currently only differentiated in the client libraries (to
>   enable APIs tailored to the usage of the specific types) and in the
>   wire protocol. The Prometheus server does not yet make use of the type
>   information and flattens all data into untyped time series.

I'm using a [remote storage adapter](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/tree/master/documentation/examples/remote_storage/remote_storage_adapter) and need data type to be sent along with each metric. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out from the documentation, the metric type is not preserved.

You can use the metric name to get a hint on what the metric represents. For example, for well instrumented applications and exporters, the suffixes `_total`, `_count`, `_bucket`, `_sum`... represent counters.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, metric type IS stored, it is just not USED(for type check or other).

You can access the information through [this API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#querying-target-metadata). While this type may not be involved with type check.